# calling resize on std vector of pointers crashed

Tags: c++, stl

The problem can be reproduced using VS 2013 Express. It crashed when internal vector implementation tried to deallocate the original vector.

However, the problem can solved by using 'new' instead of 'malloc'.

Anyone can shed some light on this?

```
struct UndirectedGraphNode {
   int label;
   vector<UndirectedGraphNode *> neighbors;
   UndirectedGraphNode(int x) : label(x) {};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    UndirectedGraphNode* node1 = (UndirectedGraphNode*)malloc(sizeof(UndirectedGraphNode));
    node1->label = 0;
    node1->neighbors.resize(2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you were doing "new" it was crashing and malloc fixed it?

Comment: You can avoid a lot of troubles if you leave behind C idioms when programming in C++.

Comment: On a side note: that non-explicit single parameter constructor for `UndirectedGraphNode` that you have there currently allows implicit conversions from `int` to `UndirectedGraphNode` which may result in some very strange behavior down the road. You should at least qualify it as `explicit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` does not create objects. It just allocates memory. To create objects (non-trivial ones, at least), you need to call a constructor. `new` does that, `malloc` does not. Your program crashes because you are treating the memory allocated by `malloc` as if there is an object there, when there is not.

Comment: In fact, referring to non-static members of a object with a non-trivial constructor before construction results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
UndirectedGraphNode* node1 = (UndirectedGraphNode*)malloc(sizeof(UndirectedGraphNode));
```

you have uninitialized memory. Use

```
UndirectedGraphNode* node1 = new  UndirectedGraphNode(0);
```

instead.

Then you can also remove the line

```
node1->label = 0;
```